# Connect to Azure Artifacts Feed from docker image running on build agent

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

My azure-pipelines.yml file

```sh
  jobs:
  - job: linux_bionic
    displayName: 'Linux (Bionic)'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'
    steps:
    - template: ci/docker.yml
      parameters:
        imageName: 'microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-bionic'
        environmentVariables: |
          BUILD_CONFIG=Release
```

My ci/docker.yml

```sh
steps:
- bash: chmod 755 ./ci/*.sh
  displayName: 'Ensure build script permissions'

- task: docker@0
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    action: 'Run an image'
    imageName: ${{ parameters.imageName }}
    volumes: |
      $(Build.SourcesDirectory):/src
      $(Build.BinariesDirectory):/build
    envVars: ${{ parameters.environmentVariables }}
    workDir: '/src'
    containerCommand: '/src/ci/build.sh'
    detached: false
```

in my build.sh i have `dotnet build` command witch is supposed to restore packages from nuget.org and also from my private azure artifacts feed

```xml
<add key="MyFeed" 
value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

This is a part of azure pipelines logs

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.8.166+gd4e8d81a88 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restoring packages for /src/src/MyProj/MyProj.csproj...
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyOrg/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json. [/src/MyProj.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.402/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/src/MyProj.sln]

Build FAILED.
```

I think it's possible to add the feed's api key in nuget.config, i have it in my global nuget.config, but i don't want to check that in source control.

Is there any way to make the feed accessible from within the docker image, the same way it's accessible from within the build agent?

Comment: I think the solution to this will be very similar to the answer I proveded here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419491/azure-artifacts-gives-unauthorized-when-trying-to-build-dockerfile/53510966#53510966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Azure Artifacts Credential Provider](https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider) in your container along with the `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` environment variable to pass in the build's access token.

Comment: This is so hacky, but i guess it's the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use endpoint credentials. 
Authenticate access with personal access tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS {\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"YOUR_FEED_URL/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"username\":\"YOUR_USER\", \"password\":\"YOUR_PAT\"}]}

WORKDIR /myapp

#Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore -s YOUR_FEED_URL/nuget/v3/index.json -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
```