# Azure Artifacts gives unauthorized when trying to build Dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker, nuget, azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps Pipelines to create a Docker image from my github repo. It is having issue however accessing the nuget package that I have hosted in Azure Artifacts. It returns unauthorized (401). As Azure Pipelines seems to be relativly new, there does not seem to be much help, and the help that is out there that is not specifically for Artifacts has not worked for me.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  imageName: 'dockerRepoName:$(build.buildId)'

steps:
- script: docker build -f dockerRepoName -t $(imageName) .
  displayName: 'docker build'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyWebsite.Website/MyWebsite.Website.csproj MyWebsite.Website/
COPY NuGet.config ./
RUN dotnet restore MyWebsite.Website/MyWebsite.Website.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyWebsite.Website
RUN dotnet build MyWebsite.Website.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MyWebsite.Website.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyWebsite.Website.dll"]
```

**Nuget.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="http_proxy" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/companyName/_packaging/MyWebsite.Api/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="http_proxy.user" value="notSureWhatUserGoesHere_TriedABunchOfDifferentOnes" />
    <add key="http_proxy.password" value="PersonalAccessTOkenFromAzureDevops" />
  </config>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="MyWebsite" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/companyName/_packaging/MyWebsite.Api/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Took out the actual user and passwords, so that obviously was not what I used for those. The urls are also updated to "companyName" since it a private repo so the url will not work.

**Build Error**

```
2018-11-21T19:21:00.0200396Z   Restoring packages for /src/MyWebsite.Website/MyWebsite.Website.csproj...
2018-11-21T19:21:00.6762563Z /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/NuGet.targets(114,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/companyName/_packaging/MyWebsite.Api/nuget/v3/index.json. [/src/MyWebsite.Website/MyWebsite.Website.csproj]
2018-11-21T19:21:00.6763038Z /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.500/NuGet.targets(114,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/src/MyWebsite.Website/MyWebsite.Website.csproj]
2018-11-21T19:21:01.0956272Z The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore MyWebsite.Website/MyWebsite.Website.csproj' returned a non-zero code: 1
2018-11-21T19:21:01.1105851Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2018-11-21T19:21:01.1192131Z ##[section]Finishing: docker build
```

Comment: Please share how did you resolve this issue with docker file. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a Personal Access Token (PAT)

   - Grant Read access to the Package section of the Scopes
2. Modify the dockerfile
3. Specify the `PAT` build argument as `docker build --build-arg PAT="{access token}"`

## Example Docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
# The Personal Access token required to access the artifacts
ARG PAT

# Install the Credential Provider to configure the access
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

# Configure the environment variables
ENV NUGET_CREDENTIALPROVIDER_SESSIONTOKENCACHE_ENABLED true
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"{package source}/index.json\", \"password\":\"${PAT}\"}]}"

WORKDIR /src


COPY ["src/Sample/Sample.csproj", "src/Sample/"]

RUN dotnet restore -s "{package source}/index.json" "src/Sample/Sample.csproj" 
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Sample"
RUN dotnet build "Sample.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Sample.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sample.dll"]
```

Comment: This is unsecure because the image history preserve the --build-args and each RUN line, hence the secret PAT will be part of the history.